# Themes are not changing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome, themes

I used **unity-tweak-tool** for changing themes it worked. Suddenly it stopped working. The font seems to be tiny than before. 
I tried by removing *unity-tweak-tool* and from *System Settings > Appearance*.

I installed **dconf-editor** and *checked* **active** from `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings`.

I tried by deleting `user` from /`home/.config/dconf/user`.

I want to add a line that I have `wine` on my laptop.

How can I resolve this problem?